# Slim append header

Tags: php, slim

I want to append token inside header in slim when $token not empty. I append new header with function **withAddedHeader()**

> from [slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html)

This is my code:

```
$res = $this->response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
if ($token !== null) {
    $res->withAddedHeader('token', $token);
}
```

But still not working, new header not appended.

Comment: The documentation says "The Response object is immutable. This method *returns a copy of the Response object* that has the appended header value." That means you need to get the new object and use it, like `$res = $res->withAddedHeader('token', $token);`

Comment: Also, just wondering, why would you want to add a header to the response? I would think you'd just want to add headers to the request.

Comment: Oh nvm, I see. Slim is the web-server in this scenario, so it is delivering the response.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks it worked like a charm. I add token to header response because the token is needed for every request (token will be regenerated for each request).

Comment: Are you using `$this->response` from the `container`, if yes that response would be stale at the point of a request, we suggest that you don't use the response from the container. Can you show a bit more of your route or middleware you are trying to do this from please?

Answer (score 2):

`with**()` method of `Response` class returns clone of current `Response` instance to maintain immutability.

To add header properly, you need to return newly cloned response before exiting route handler.

```
$res = $this->response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

if ($token !== null) {
    return $res->withAddedHeader('token', $token);
}

return $res;
```